# SQL (Access) - Only Show Row With More Information

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Good morning.

I am currently building a report that features Name, Document type, and Expiration Date. The query is based on whether or not the document was ever requested (=yes) and the individual's role/position. Sadly, due to how the database was designed and how the users have used it, a person may have two roles (Lead Coordinator/Coordinator), and as such, two separate entries (IDs) in the database. However, the users have often only entered in the "Expiration Date" for one of those entries.

Thus, now when I have queries gathering Name, Document, and Expiration Date for each role and then combining them via Union, there may be multiple entries per person, such as:

```
Smith, John AAA 11-5-2012
Smith, John AAA
Doe, Jane AAA 
Doe, Jane AAA 11-11-2011
```

Is there a way that I am able to keep the row that has more information?

*NOTE* I do NOT want to due it based on "Date <> Null" because sometimes we may have requested the document but we have not received it yet to enter the Expiration Date and we need to be able to see this data in case we need to request it once again.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max and Group By may suit:

```
SELECT Docs.Person, Docs.Doc, Max(Docs.DateEntered) AS MaxOfDateEntered
FROM Docs
GROUP BY Docs.Person, Docs.Doc;
```

Where Docs is the name of your table or query.

Input:

```
Person      Doc DateEntered
Smith,John  AAA 11-5-2012
Smith,John  AAA 
Doe,Jane    AAA 
Doe,Jane    AAA
```

Result:

```
Person      Doc MaxOfDateEntered
Doe,Jane    AAA 
Smith,John  AAA 11-5-2012
```

Edit re comment

```
SELECT doc.Name, doc.Site, doc.Document, Max(doc.Expr1003) AS MaxOfExpr1003
FROM doc
GROUP BY doc.Name, doc.Site, doc.Document;
```

Edit re comment #2

```
SELECT 
    ResultsTbl.Name, 
    ResultsTbl.Site, 
    ResultsTbl.Document, 
    Max(ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date) AS Expiration_Date 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        lname & ', ' & fname AS Name, 
        site_name AS Site, 
        Document, cv_request_expires_on AS Expiration_Date 
    FROM Coord_CV_Expiration 
    UNION SELECT 
        lname & ', ' & fname AS Name, 
        site_name AS Site, 
        Document, 
        cv_request_expires_on AS Expiration_Date 
    FROM LeadCoord_CV_Expiration ...) AS ResultsTbl 
GROUP BY ResultsTbl.Site, ResultsTbl.Document, ResultsTbl.Name
ORDER BY ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date;
```

Note that you should not GROUP By Expiration Date.

Comment: If the above edit does not work, perhaps you could post real data to your question? Fake data very rarely suits when you are looking for a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It makes complete sense, but for some reason it is not working!   
It still returns:    
"O___, E____ G C, Ltd. AA 9/10/2014    
O___, E____ G C, Ltd. AA     
O___, E____ G C, Ltd. BB     
O___, E____ G C, Ltd. BB 7/12/2013"    
    
The code I used is:    
`SELECT ResultsTbl.Name, ResultsTbl.Site, ResultsTbl.Document, Max(ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date) AS Expiration_Date` after storing Union set AS ResultsTbl.

Comment: Here's a snippet of the full code:  
`SELECT ResultsTbl.Name, ResultsTbl.Site, ResultsTbl.Document, Max(ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date) AS Expiration_Date
FROM (SELECT lname & ', ' & fname AS Name, site_name AS Site, Document, cv_request_expires_on AS Expiration_Date
FROM Coord_CV_Expiration
UNION
SELECT lname & ', ' & fname AS Name, site_name AS Site, Document, cv_request_expires_on AS Expiration_Date
FROM LeadCoord_CV_Expiration
...)  AS ResultsTbl
GROUP BY ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date, ResultsTbl.Site, ResultsTbl.Document, ResultsTbl.Name
ORDER BY ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date;`

Comment: Do not GROUP BY on ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date, you want the max only on that.

Comment: It seems Access essentially forces me to! Without it I get the warning: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: But you *should* have it as part of an aggregate function, you should have `Max(ResultsTbl.Expiration_Date)`. Did you build using the query design window? If not, try it.

Comment: Thank you! Switching it to design view and doing it that way worked! Much appreciated. :)